# Creating Polygonal Objects with VB6

Tags: vb6, drawing

I am developing an application, where I need to be able to draw floor plans but I need the lines drawn to act more or less as object. For instance I need to be able to click on a Line, or in case that it is associated with a room, to highlight all the lines from a room.

I need not code samples necessarily, but also some quidance or ideas.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Adding more detail and showing what you've attempted so far would be good.  Have an attempt yourself and come here when you need help with actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create classes such as Line, Room etc.

Room contains a list of Lines.

A Line has the draw() and contains(x as integer, y as integer) methods.

To implement contains:
You can figure out the equation of the line given the starting and ending point. Then you could calculate the distance of a point (x0,y0) from that line (ax + by +c = 0) using the formula distance = abs(a*x0 + b*y0 + c) / sqrt(a * a + b*b)
if the distance is 4 pixels or less then contains should be true.

similar to the line, curves have an equation describing them. 
For example Beziers and B-splines have corresponding equations. 
Using those equations you can draw them and figure out the distance of the mouse from them.

For Bezier curves see:
http://blog.gludion.com/2009/08/distance-to-quadratic-bezier-curve.html

The circle for example it's the easiest.

`distance = abs(radius - sqrt((mouseX - centerX)^2 + (mouseY - centerY)^2)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea! Look like will take a use of it. Only one things remains unclear- what abour curves? Or semicircles for instance,

Comment: similar to the line, curves have an equation describing them. For example Beziers and B-splines have corresponding equations. using those equations you can draw them and figure out the distance of the mouse from them. For the circle for example it's the easiest. `mouse distance from perimeter = abs(radius - sqrt((mouseX - centerX)^2 + (mouseY - centerY)^2)`